# html, css, or javascript - preventing the browser to change the layout upon resize

Tags: html, css

So I am creating a website and I've run across this issue. I have search around the internet and couldn't really find a solution to this problem even though I know sites like facebook.com does it.

I want to be able to restrict the resizing of my site's layout at a certain point. Is there some kind of CSS function which restricts the whole site's minimum width and height?

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: Search for **CSS Media Queries**

Comment: Users don't bother about such effects because i don't think that any user don't use their full screen when viewing the web

Comment: Have you looked at the 960 grid system?

Comment: @Ankit That's untrue. I use 2 27" monitors and it's pretty rare for me to use a browser fullscreen. It's a waste of space when most sites fill up only like half of it.

Comment: @Chelsea then you resize to a normal resolution(like 1280X768) or a resolution of 400X400

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that these lines of code work:

```
div {
   min-width:1000 px;
   min-height: 1000px;
}
```